# Android DrawerLayout height

Tags: android

He's using the NavigationView with the support library android.support.design.widget. It works very well but I can not adjust the height and the margins, then it remains empty space between the toolbar and the first line. To understand the problem see the image. This is my XML. Thanks for your help.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/main"/>
    <!-- app:headerLayout="@layout/header" -->
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

toolbar_default

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
    />
```

[image]

Comment: put code layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
menu

Comment: Add code for "@style/ToolBarStyle"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `dimens.xml`,

```
<dimen name="design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding">0dp</dimen>
```

Comment: no, unfortunately nothing changes. I also tried: android:minHeight="0dp"